# How can I get a list of meetings only?

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS and I want to get a list of appointments that are meetings. Exchanges defines meetings as appointments that have attendees. I am currently doing this:

```
var filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection
             {
                 //new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting, true),
                 new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)),
                 new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Today),
             };
var results = service.FindItems(id, filter, view);
```

With the `IsMeeting` filter commented, it successfully returns all appointments and I can loop through the results and see the `IsMeeting` property is set correctly. I would like to only get appointments that are meetings. So I added the commented line and also tried:

```
new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting, true)
new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting, "true")
new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting, 1)
new SearchFilter.Exists(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting)
```

Yet I continue to get this error: `The property can not be used with this type of restriction.` Any Ideas?

Comment: I am using Exchange 2010 SP2.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't debug your code to see why you're getting the error, but I'd recommend using the CalendarFolder.FindAppointments method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd636179(v=exchg.80).aspx) with a CalendarView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.calendarview(v=exchg.80).aspx) to filter your results.

There's a code sample for retrieving appointments on this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx, have you seen this?

Comment: I don't think the `FindAppointments` and `CalendarView` supports paging because it expands recurring events. I will play with this method a bit but paging is something I can't give up.

Comment: `FindAppointments` does not have a filter option. `CalendarView` seems to only support a date range filter. It looks like I'm stuck filtering after the EWS call.